# simple-form association gives "undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

In my Rails 3 application, I have the following simple relational structure:

```
class Rollout < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items, :through => :rollout_items
end

class RolloutItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :rollout
    belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rollouts, :through => :rollout_items
end
```

Controller:

```
def new
    @rollout = Rollout.new
end
```

I get the above error with the following form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @rollout do |f| %>
    <%= f.association :items %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How is `@rollout` defined in your controller?

Comment: Updated to answer your question.

Comment: The relationship between `Rollout` and `RolloutItem` has also been defined, I suppose? Namely: `has_many :rollout_items`.

Comment: No it had not, that is what was missing. I assumed that it would be implicitly defined when defining the relationship to Item. Please post your solution and I'll accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a missing relationship between `Rollout` and `RolloutItem`:

```
class Rollout < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rollout_items # This.
    has_many :items, :through => :rollout_items
end
```

The same goes for `Item`.